# Elegant C# method to return an IEnumerable<T> from a function which is bool TryParse<T>(Input, out T) and an input[,]

Tags: c#

Is there an elegant way to build an `IEnumerable<T>` from

```
bool TryParse<T>(Input, out T)
```

and an input of type

```
Input[,]
```

Basically I have a 2D array of Input and would like to call TryParse on each Input, if `TryParse<T>` returns true I will append the return value in 'out' to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

I can do this easily in a for loop but I wanted something more elegant. This is what I use at the moment:

```
        var marketInputColl = new Collection<MarketInput>();
        foreach (object o in marketInputs)
        {
            MarketInput mktInput;
            if (ExcelCache.TryGetCache<MarketInput>(o.ToString(), out mktInput))
                marketInputColl.Add(mktInput);
        }
```

Comment: Is `Input` a type? What did you try?

Comment: There are "elegant" ways to do what you want, but they'll be more convoluted and harder to understand than a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: I realize that this is not a 100% duplicate, but it's a trivial extension from iterating through a 2D array.

Comment: @Heinzi yes but using addition operator on generics is not that easy

Comment: `Input` is a type, I am fine using a for loop, I do not know how to add to the Enum selectively in function of the return value of TryParse in a LINQ expression.

Comment: @BlueTrin it would help if you show the declaration of Input and how do you plan to use it with linq with an example,

Comment: Sure I will try and report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

out/ref parameters don't exactly play all that well with LINQ.  You can do it, but it's messy.  The preferable option is to use a parsing tool that will return a nullable int (with null if the value cannot be parsed) instead of using `out`:

```
public static int? TryParse(string s)
{
    int output;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out output))
        return output;
    else
        return null;
}
```

You can make a comparable function for your attempts to fetch the value from the cache, so long as you don't also need to store *actual* `null` values.

This allows you to write:

```
var query = data.Select(item => TryGetCache(item.ToString()))
    .Where(n => n != null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a generic way:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public delegate bool TryParseDelegate<TSource>(string s, out TSource source);

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> WhereParsed<TSource, TResult>(
                                               this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                               TryParseDelegate<TResult> tryParse)
    {
        // check arguments against null first

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            TResult result;
            if (tryParse(item.ToString(), out result))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = marketInputs.Cast<object>()
                         .WhereParsed<object, MarketInput> 
                                     // need to specify explicit,
                                    // out param type cannot be inferred from usage
                              (ExcelCache.TryGetCache).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `TryParse()` is that it's not an implementation of any interface: you'll either need to use reflection to find the method, or (simpler), just provide a conversion delegate.

Then you can do something like this, with a 2D array (or actually, arrays of any number of dimensions:

```
string[,] raw = { { "1" , "2" , } ,
                  { "3" , "X" , } ,
                  { "5" , "6" , } ,
                } ;
int?[] converted = raw.Cast<string>()
                   .Select( s => {
                     int value ;
                     bool parsed = int.TryParse( s , out value ) ;
                     return parsed ? (int?) value : (int?)null ;
                   })
                   .ToArray()
                   ;
```

If your array is jagged, you'll need one more step:

```
string[][] raw = { new string[]{"1","2",} ,
                   new string[]{"3","X",} ,
                   new string[]{"5","6",} ,
                 } ;
int?[] converted = raw.Cast<string[]>()
                   .SelectMany( s => s )
                   .Select( s => {
                     int  value ;
                     bool parsed = int.TryParse( s , out value ) ;
                     return parsed ? (int?) value : (int?)null ;
                   })
                   .ToArray()
                   ;
```

Given your example:

```
var marketInputColl = new Collection<MarketInput>();

foreach (object o in marketInputs)
{
  MarketInput mktInput;
  if (ExcelCache.TryGetCache<MarketInput>(o.ToString(), out mktInput))
    marketInputColl.Add(mktInput);
}
```

We can take the same basic approach:

```
Collection<MarketInput> collection = new Collection<MarketInput>(
  marketInputs
  .Cast<object>()
  .Select( o => o.ToString() )
  .Select( s => {
    MarketInput v ;
    bool parsed = ExcelCache.TryGetCache<MarketInput>( s , out v ) ;
    return parsed ? v : null ;
  })
  .Where( x => x != null )
  .ToList()
  ) ;
```